# Laravel failed job is not retrying

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I have a job that has `public $tries = 2;` but when it fails, it does not retry. In Horizon, I have to retry the job manually.

Here is the job:

```
class SendEmailMessage implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $message;
    public $tries = 2;

    public function __construct(EmailMessage $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function handle(EmailMessageRepository $emailMessageRepository)
    {
        app()->setLocale($this->message->organization->locale);
        $emailMessageRepository->send($this->message);
    }
}
```

Here is the queue config:

```
'email' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
    'queue' => 'email',
    'retry_after' => 90,
    'block_for' => null,
],
```

And the Horizon supervisor config:

```
'supervisor-2' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => ['media', 'email', 'sms'],
    'balance' => 'simple',
    'processes' => 1,
    'tries' => 2,
],
```

Why isn't Horizon retrying the job when it fails? Am I missing something?

Comment: I’m not sure there is enough info here to give an answer. But couple of comments - 1) your queue retries after 90secs. Are you waiting that long to check? 2) I haven’t used horizon for ages, but isn’t it just a package to monitor the queues? It doesn’t actually perform “retry” actions so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the job was being dispatched from within a DB transaction and so the row in the database didn't yet exist.

Mohamed from Laravel Forge suggested I use the method `afterCommit()`.
See [Jobs & Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#jobs-and-database-transactions) for details.

That resolved the issue. The second try wasn't necessary.